# How to retain the reference of [x]-number of viewControllers without declaration

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller, retain-cycle

I have a mainViewController in which I want to show a small gridlike formation of an undefined count of childViewControllers. The childViewControllers is created on the basis of data and therefore I can't know the count of them in advance. As it seems, I can only interact with f.ex. buttons in the childViewController if it is retained by the mainViewController (f.ex. in a declared variable) - so my question is, how do I retain the reference between the mainViewController and the [x]-number of childViewControllers without declaring them as individual variables?

I've tried to create parent variable on the childController and set it to the mainViewController, but this doesn't solve the problem - (the buttons in the childViewController is only functionable if I declare each childController individually..) I've tried to create an array of childControllers and adding them to that in the mainViewController, but also this doesn't work.

I'm looking not to use collectionView as there will be alot of customization and animations involved, so what is the correct method to retain these childViewControllers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly:

UIViewController has a property `childViewControllers` which is an array.

You can read https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller 's *Implementing a Container View Controller* section to understand how to add you child view controllers properly.

Then you can just use array subscripts to get you [x] child view controller like this:

```
myContainerViewController.childViewControllers[x].whateverButton ...
// or
let childX = myContainerViewController.childViewControllers[x]
childX.doSomething()
```

The `childViewControllers` array in your parent view controller will retain you child view controllers.

EDIT:

If you need access to properties of your subclasses then you have to downcast UIViewController to you subclass [swift4 link, should be the same for swift3](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html)

You downcast like this:

```
if let child = mycontainerVC.childViewControllers[x] as? MySubclassOfUIViewController {
    child.subclassProperty = 1 // or whatever
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot! :-) I must have made a rookie-mistake when I tried the array-solution because I couldn't get it to work before (no reaction on my childControllers) but trying it out again it works just fine, as well as the info in the documentation about using the "addChildViewController(_:)" also works for me.